# Seleccionar Primer registro de varios registros repetidos SQL Server

Tags: sql

Siempre tengo la misma duda cada vez que se me presenta esta situación.
Necesito seleccionar el primer registro de cada registro duplicado.

Ejemplo, estos son los registros que me trae una consulta X:

```
Puerta | Orden | Observación
PLA      111       GAA1
PLA      111       RUJ2
PLA      112       ASRU
PLA      112       BIC
PLA      113       2PAR
PLA      113       7ACa
```

Y necesito que me quede así:

```
Puerta | Orden | Observación
PLA      111       GAA1
PLA      112       ASRU
PLA      113       2PAR
```

Comment: las filas en una tabla no tienen un orden implícito...cómo sabemos cuál es el "primer" elemento?, necesitamos el criterio de ordenación que quieres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La opción más simple es utilizar row_number para numerar las filas

```
create Table dbo.source  (Puerta varchar(3), orden smallint, Observacion varchar(4))
go
Insert into dbo.source (Puerta, orden, Observacion)
values
('PLA',111,'GAA1'),
('PLA',111,'RUJ2'),
('PLA',112,'ASRU'),
('PLA',112,'BIC'),
('PLA',113,'2PAR'),
('PLA',113,'7ACa');
go
```

Con una tabla de expresión común

```
with c as (
    select *,
            ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Puerta, orden order by puerta,orden,observacion) as rn
    from dbo.source
    )
Select c.Puerta, c.orden, c.Observacion from c
where rn=1;
```

O con una tabla derivada.

```
Select d.Puerta, d.orden, d.Observacion from
(
    select *,
            ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Puerta, orden order by puerta,orden, observacion) as rn
    from dbo.source
) as d
where d.rn =1;
```

El juego está en el `partition by Puerta, orden`. Con esto cada vez que cambie Puerta u orden reinicia la numeración, por tanto solo los 1 son únicos.

[image: Res]

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Así, en plan rápido, puedes usar GROUP BY

```
SELECT * FROM tabla GROUP BY Orden
```

Pero lo que veo en el ejemplo no son registros duplicados, el campo observación es diferente. Pero con esto consigues el resultado que citas en la pregunta.